# React stateless function component missing props but no propType warnings in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following stateless functional component:

```
function numberOfReadsControls(props) {
return (
    <div>
        <ControlLabel>Start Date</ControlLabel>
        <DateField
            dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
            defaultValue={props.reportParams.startDate}
            updateOnDateClick={true}
            onChange={props.startCalOnChange}/>
        <br/><br/>
        {/* more selectors here, removed for brevity*/}
    </div>
);
}

numberOfReadsControls.propTypes = {
    startCalOnChange: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    //more props removed for brevity
    testMissingProp: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

module.exports = {
    numberOfReadsControls

}
```

and I use this function like this in my render function:

```
controls = reportControls.numberOfReadsControls(
                $.extend({
                    //props removed for brevity
                    startCalOnChange: this.startCalOnChange,
                }, this.state)
            );
```

then later in the return of my render function:

```
...
return (
<div>
    {controls}
</div>
)
```

However, I never get a console warning about the missing prop "testMissingProp".

What am I doing wrong?

tldr: I have a stateless functional component with required props, but when one is missing I don't get any logging statement saying there is a missing prop as expected

Comment: Is the component rendering as intended?

Comment: Doesn't your `controls` need to be wrapped as `{controls}`? Otherwise, the component will render as `<div>controls</div>`

Comment: The component does render exactly as expected. The only thing I'm missing is the expected warning telling me about the missing prop.

Comment: yes you're right, it is rendered as `{controls}`. I edited the snippet

Comment: To my eyes it looks like you're doing a bit of an end-run around normal react component processing; you're basically just calling a function, no? E.g., if you imported it and rendered it as a component, like `<NumberOfReadControls {...extendedProps} />` I'd guess it would work.

Comment: React components should start with upper case. Does this solve it?

Comment: @Dave Newton This [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html) shows the Reactjs documentation for what I'm trying to do. Scroll to "Stateless Functions".  
 Case of the function names did not affect anything.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of what stateless functions are. What I'm saying is that you're not using them the way (a) they are, or (b) the way I'd expect them to actually work. IMO you're just calling a function rather than running it through the normal React component rendering process.

Comment: @PiotrBerebecki That's a convention, not a requirement.

Comment: @DaveNewton You are exactly right! If you post this as the answer I'll accept it. changing it to `controls = <NumberOfReadsControls />` in the render function made it start throwing the errors I expected. I guess I assumed I could just call the function since it is one. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it *is* a function, but it needs to run through the normal React rendering process so React has a chance to do things like check the properties.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, once I realized I was mis-reading the documentation. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @DaveNewton, the react docs use the word 'convention' but it seems that we have no choice and we have to follow it. Have a look here: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/RGjLyd ; and change  `App` to `app` in two places.